# Increase ARM CustomScriptExtension log size

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

When using the ARM CustomScriptExtension, I noticed that the logs under

```
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.9.3\Status
```

have a max size of 5kb.  If my script logs more than that, the extension will only keep the latter entries.  Is this log size configurable?